# If $f'(x)=\sqrt{x+1}$ and $h(x)=f(x^2+x)$, what is $h'(x)$?

Tags: calculus

I was thinking it could be plugging in $x^2+x$ to the $f'(x)$, then using the Chain Rule to solve it, but I'm not sure if it is right. Please help!

Comment: Yes, use the chain rule.

Comment: I got the answer $\frac{2x+1}{2\sqrt{x^2+x+1}}$. Is this correct?

Comment: @TZike: it’s wrong . See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Put $u = x^2+x$ then the Chain Rule says that: $h’(x) = f’(u)\cdot u’(x) = \sqrt{u+1}\cdot (2x+1) = (2x+1)\cdot \sqrt{x^2+x+1}$.

Answer (score 1):

If $f'(x) = \sqrt{x+1}$, then $f(x) = \int \sqrt{x+1} dx = \frac{2}{3}(x+1)^{\frac{3}{2}} + c$. You can solve that integral using u-substitution. Then we also know that $h(x) = f(x^2 + x)$. So then using function notation, we know that $h(x) = f(x^2 + x) = \frac{2}{3}(x^2 + x+1)^{\frac{3}{2}} + c$. We can now differentiate this using chain rule as follows:

$h(x) = \frac{2}{3}(x^2 + x+1)^{\frac{3}{2}} + c$

$h'(x) = \frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{3}{2}(x^2 + x+1)^{\frac{1}{2}} \cdot (2x+1) = (x^2 + x+1)^{\frac{1}{2}} \cdot (2x+1) $

Notice that when we do so, the derivative of $c$ will just be $0$, so it doesn't matter that we don't know the specific value of $c$.